# Удаление записей MySQL автоматом

Tags: asp.net, forms, sql-server

Как без планировщика задач и агента MsSQL удалять записи из таблицы спустя неделю, две или четыре. Количество недель определяется столбцом в таблице.

Comment: Вам необходимо удалить именно все записи или те, которые по счету больше тридцатой ?

Comment: Нужно совсем по - другому, вопрос поменял.

Comment: [Возможный дубликат](http://hashcode.ru/questions/108954/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если уж совсем извращаться, то можно такое сделать либо с помощью триггеров (при определенных условиях) либо скриптом, который будет имитировать того же SQL Agent'a (например, бесконечный цикл с конструкцией WAITFOR). Но как правильно заметил [@minamoto](/users/3171/minamoto) такую задачу лучше решать с помощью стандартных средств - SQL Agent, или написать скрипт и периодически запускать его вручную.

Comment: Ну, вручную, это можно и на Button_Click повесить, а про SQL Agent - он запускаться не хочет.

Comment: Если не можете разобраться, почему не запускается SQL Agent - что мешает рядом открыть еще одну тему, в которой описать - какие именно ошибки выдает SQL Agent при попытке запуска? Навскидку - могу посоветовать проверить, от какой учетной записи он запускается - от существующей или нет.

Answer (score 1):

Вручную. Будильник себе поставьте и удаляйте.

Что за вопрос? Почему нужно отказываться от использования SQL Agent'а или планировщика?